# pyQT6 insertar un botón en el widget QDateEdit para seleccionar la fecha actual

Tags: python, pyqt6

pyQT6 no tiene un botón para seleccionar la fecha en curso en el control QDateEdit

He definido un botón QPushButton y lo he incluido en el calendarWidget().layout(). Funciona, salvo:

- Cuando se pulsa el botón no cierra el calendario. La solución de hacer un calendarWidget().hide() lo oculta, pero deja visible el marco
- Despues de eso no hay forma de volver a visualizar el calendario.
  Dejo un ejemplo *operativo*.

Alguna idea? Gracias.

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QDate
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QDateEdit,
    QPushButton,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QWidget)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
   
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()

        # selección de fecha
        self.fecha = QDateEdit()
        self.fecha.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.fecha.setDate(QDate.currentDate())
        self.fecha.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading|Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignTop)

        # botón para seleccionar fecha actual
        self.hoy = QPushButton('Hoy')
    
        # añadir botón al calendario
        self.fecha.calendarWidget().layout().addWidget(self.hoy)
        # conectar con función para actualizar la fecha
        self.hoy.clicked.connect(self._update_today)
    
        self.layout.addWidget(self.fecha)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.layout)
    
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def _update_today(self):
        self.fecha.setDate(QDate.currentDate())
        # cerrar el calendario después de pulsar el botón
        self.fecha.calendarWidget().hide()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.resize(435, 284)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Estás en [es.so]. Haz clic en [edit] y traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada. Tienes suficiente reputación en el sitio para saber las normas del sitio.

Comment: Voy a ello, pero a las 2 de la madrugada no te creas que tenía todas las neuronas funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema en cuestión se debe a que QCalendarWidget está dentro de otro widget, al cual llamaste marco. Por lo tanto, el que debes cerrar u ocultar es ese widget.

Para obtener el marco, podemos usar el método [`parentWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtWidgets/QWidget.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget.parentWidget), quedando esa parte del código así:

```
self.fecha.calendarWidget().parentWidget().close()
```

Si suponemos que un widget_a contiene a un widget_b. Hacer `widget_b.parentWidget()` nos devuelve widget_a, es decir, el padre o pariente.

Finalmente, no se si se debe cerrar u ocultar el widget, ni las consecuencias que ésto tenga internamente. Aún así, espero haber ayudado.

Comment: Gracias, Dante. Funciona perfectamente. Como decía, el widget QDateEdit no tiene un botón para seleccionar el día en curso ( o yo no se como sacarlo) , así que se me ocurrió añadir un botón. Y funcionaba, pero no tenía forma de cerrar el calendario. Ahora sí, con tu sugerencia marcha muy bien.